# How to develop a public key cryptosystem based on a hard problem?

Tags: public-key, complexity

Recently, I found a function that is performed on a sequence to return another sequence. All known algorithms for finding the input, given the output are of exponential complexity. I want to propose this function for encryption in a public key cryptosystem. What steps I am supposed to take? Actually I am a beginner in cryptography.

Comment: Why do you need to propose this algorithm?Does it outperforms the existing ones?What you are describing sounds as a pseudorandom generator

Comment: You only described a one-way function so far, something similar to a hash function. You didn't say where the asymmetric component comes in.

Comment: @curious. Actually, I want to know whether it outperforms the existing ones or no!

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks. Actually, I want to find out how can I take an asymmetric component out of it. How should I start? I only know that hard problems are suitable for asymmetric cryptography. I am at the beginning of a cryptography course.

Comment: For asymmetric encryption or key-exchange your system needs lots of mathematical structure. Almost all one-way functions are not suitable. For example with diffie-hellman key-exchange you not only need the property that $A=G^a \mod p$ is hard to invert, you also have the property that $A^b=(G^a)^b = G^{ab} = (G^b)^a = B^a$ i.e. you are able to compute the same shared secret using $A$ and $b$ or $B$ and $a$. Where lowercase letters are private keys and upper case letters the corresponding public keys.

Comment: We know many many hard to invert functions, but only a handful of fundamentally different asymmetric encryption/key-exchange schemes.

Comment: Is there any survey/collection to get familiar with such functions?

Comment: @ChodesInChaos: I think when speaking of public key encryption, these properties you require for key exchange may be a bit misleading. Think for instance of code based cryptosystems. Typically you require some trapdoor in combination with a hard problem (like decoding random linear codes in code based crypto). But having a candidate function is not the entire story. You need efficiency, suitable key and ciphertext sizes as well as other properties besides one-wayness as IND-CPA security. Far away from a trivial task :/

Comment: @DrLecter Thanks. Is there any survey on such functions and the way they are exploited in cryptography?

Comment: You may have a look at the [ECRYPT Wiki](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/wiki/index.php/Hard_Problems_in_Cryptography) for an overview of hard problems used in crypto schemes (but thats not complete). Are you familiar with basic crypto?

Comment: I am attending the course. So far I've been taught number theory and classic cryptosystems.

Comment: @DrLecter I didn't say that you need that specific property. But that you need a non trivial mathematical property beyond one-way-ness. Commutativity is one example, many other schemes rely on a trapdoor. The chance that an arbitrary hard to invert function has such a property is very small.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I totally agree! And as said, then you still are not finished. @ Mahdi: Maybe you want to present your ideas in more details? If not, you can surely consult your Prof.

Comment: I think what we are seeing here is that there is no set process for taking a hard problem and turning it into a public key cryptosystem. I agree with DrLecter that you probably need to post more details here about your specific problem before we can help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about cryptography at all, but about the process of disseminating and/or producing results.